# should the Terms & Conditions button be displayed on main screen?

Tags: android, login

We have a Mobile Application Login Screen, and it should contain a button to open the terms & Conditions screen, and there is a suggestion to show that button under overflow menu, so it will not be visible to the user until he clicks the overflow menu

example of overflow menu 
[image]

is this approach is user friendly?

the application is generic app for travellers (hotels booking), and the user doesn't need to accept the terms before using the app (casual when you use the app you agree the terms and conditions)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Answering such questions without context is really hard, though. If you tell us a little more about your users (casual usage vs. regular contributors vs. employees of your company vs...) and the need to see the terms (agreement needed before use of the app, special or non-standard regulations, etc.), you will get better (and more!) answers.

Comment: @virtualnobi sorry, this is my first post here, i just edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the terms and conditions isn't a menu entry which the user frequently uses my personal opinion would be to nest it within the settings. Popular applications like Google etc. tend to 'hide' this information too. So if its not absolutely necessary to inform your user base about your terms and conditions (maybe for legal reasons) there is no reason to 'waste' the space and should be used for a more frequently used functionallity.

Comment: Yep.Sign up page: prominent. Otherwise easily accessible in footer, on account or settings page/menu.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless if the approach is user friendly or not, your lawyers will tell you to put it back in sight, as the laws of most lands require it visible and clickable easily other wise if someone decides to sue you, they can argue there were no terms when I signed up/logged in.

Check with your lawyers.

Comment: Did you mean "back in sight" or indeed "back on the site"? Sign up is where it should be prominently visible. Login not so much. Generally it should be easily accessible whether logged in or not. For example in the footer of a website or in some account page. The latter will work for mobile as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixed. "back in sight"